# Why I can't access to the message queue in shared memory within a container?

Tags: c++, containers, ipc, shared-memory

I work inside a container and I have a struct like below and I created a shared space in memory with the ipc library.

```
template <typename Msg_t>
struct Message_struct {
  pthread_mutex_t mtx;
  int front = 0;
  int tail = 0;
  int num_msgs = 0;
  Msg_t msg_queue[Q_SIZE];
};
```

When the server put the message in the msg_queue, it works, but when the client try to access to the queue returns segmentation fault. In particular, the client is able to access to the other variables in the struct, but not to the queue.

What is a possible problem?

Follow the function to manage the struct and initialize the shared memory

```
template <typename Msg_t>
void shm_init(Message_struct<Msg_t>* shm){
  shm->front = shm->tail = 0;
  shm->num_msgs = 0;

  pthread_mutexattr_t attrs;
  pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrs);
  pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attrs, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
  pthread_mutex_init(&shm->mtx, &attrs);
}

template <typename Msg_t>
Message_struct<Msg_t>* shm_init_receiver(key_t k, Msg_t) {
  Message_struct<Msg_t>* shm;
  int shmid;
  size_t shm_size = sizeof(Message_struct<Msg_t>);

  shmid = shmget(k, shm_size, 0666);
  if (shmid == -1) {
    AERROR << "get shm failed, error: " << strerror(errno);
    return nullptr;
  }

  shm = (Message_struct<Msg_t>*)shmat(shmid, nullptr, 0);
  if (shm == reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1)) {
    AERROR << "attach shm failed.";
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
    return nullptr;
  }
  return shm;
}

template <typename Msg_t>
Message_struct<Msg_t>* shm_init_transmitter(key_t k,
                                            Msg_t) {
  Message_struct<Msg_t>* shm;
  int shmid;
  size_t shm_size = sizeof(Message_struct<Msg_t>);

  shmid = shmget(k, shm_size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT /*| IPC_EXCL*/);
  if (shmid == -1) {
    AERROR << "get shm failed, error: " << strerror(errno);
    return nullptr;
  }

  shm = (Message_struct<Msg_t>*)shmat(shmid, nullptr, 0);
  if (shm == reinterpret_cast<void*>(-1)) {
    AERROR << "attach shm failed.";
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
    return nullptr;
  }
  return shm;
}

template <typename Msg_t>
void shm_push(Msg_t msg, Message_struct<Msg_t>* shm) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&shm->mtx);
  if(shm->num_msgs == Q_SIZE){
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm->mtx);
    return;
  }
  shm->msg_queue[shm->front] = msg;
  shm->front = (shm->front + 1) % Q_SIZE;
  shm->num_msgs++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm->mtx);
}

template <typename Msg_t>
bool shm_pop(Message_struct<Msg_t>* shm, Msg_t* msg) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&shm->mtx);
  if(shm->num_msgs == 0){
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm->mtx);
    return false;
  }

  *msg = shm->msg_queue[shm->tail];
  shm->tail = (shm->tail + 1) % Q_SIZE;
  shm->num_msgs--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&shm->mtx);
  
  return true;
}
```

Msg_t type are classes derivated from protobuf file.

Comment: Seems more C++ than C. Can you share Msg_t type and how you handle this memory ?

Comment: Which container mechanism are you using ? Lxc ?

Comment: Which kind of IPC are you using ? sysV (shmget(), shmat()...) or POSIX (shm_open()...) ?